# How to check whether div contains error message or not? If yes append new error messages to it or add a new one using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm validating a form using jQuery. I want to display error messages in one div. With the code that I've written I'm able to add one error message but I'm not understanding how to add more error messages to the one which is already present on a form. This one is added by me.

But it also needs to check if there are no error messages present in a div then we should not append the other error messages, we should add the first one and then g on for appending other error messages if any are there.

How to achieve this? Please help me.

Following is the code with which I'm able to add one error message but having issue with checking the whether the div contains error messages or not and if yes append the new error message or add the first error message and subsequently append others to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#receipt_image').bind('change', function() {
        var fileInput = $("#receipt_image")[0];  
        var ImgSizeInBytes = fileInput.files[0].size;
        if(ImgSizeInBytes > 10485760) {
            var htmlStr = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>The file you are trying to upload exceeds 10MB upload limit.</div>";    
            $(htmlStr).insertBefore('div.modal-body #rebate_request_form');        
        } else if(ImgSizeInBytes <= 10485760) {
            if ($('.alert-danger').length) {
                $('.alert-danger').remove();
            }  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try something like $('#divdestination').append($('#alertdiv').html());

Comment: I thing the best way to display error messages in to use list like ul or ol. just create an empty list and check weather it contains any element in it or not then append other messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#receipt_image').bind('change', function() {
        var fileInput = $("#receipt_image")[0];  
        var ImgSizeInBytes = fileInput.files[0].size;
        if ($('.alert-danger').length) {
            $('.alert-danger').remove();
        if(ImgSizeInBytes > 10485760) {
            var htmlStr = "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>The file you are trying to upload exceeds 10MB upload limit.</div>";    
            $(htmlStr).insertBefore('div.modal-body #rebate_request_form');        
        } 
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#receipt_image').bind('change', function() {
        var htmlStrobj = $("<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' id='errordiv' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button></div>");
        var fileInput = $("#receipt_image")[0];  
        var ImgSizeInBytes = fileInput.files[0].size;
        if ($('#errordiv').length) {
            $('#errordiv').remove();
        if(ImgSizeInBytes > 10485760) {
            var htmlStr = "The file you are trying to upload exceeds 10MB upload limit.</br >";    
            htmlStrobj.append(htmlStr);        
        } 
        // You can add more validation rules here
        htmlStrobj.insertBefore('div.modal-body #rebate_request_form');        
    });
});
```

Comment: You have just pasted the code I've written. I want to append error message to the one which exists already on a form. How to do that?

Comment: just pasted??? cant you see that the else part is removed and the logic which was inside that is moved on top of if condition?. the reason for that is now first the code will remove the error message div and put the new error message.

Comment: Actually I wan to do more validations and if I got error from those validations how should I append to the existing error message? That is my issue.

Comment: wrap it up with a div and append all error message to that. wait i will update the code

Comment: Thanks for the help you provided till now. Can you please add something more to your answer? You haven't checked whether the object htmlStrobj previously contains any error message or not. You are just appending new error messages to it. If it is blank then the error message should get added not appended. If it's not blank then it should append to existing error message. How to achieve that thing?

Comment: appending to an empty div = adding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66708/discussion-between-cerlin-boss-and-phpnut).